# How can I allow a worker role hosted in an azure cloud service to send a request to localhost?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an azure cloud service project with a WorkerRole that has two parts:

- WebApi
- Quartz.net scheduler that attempts to send a REST request to the webapi at localhost on port 80

However the scheduler is failing to connect to the REST endpoint on the api and when I have remoted into the vm it I cannot browse locally to the endpoint either.

Is there some special setting or workaround to allow the scheduler to call the webapi, or do I need to host them separately (or look into alternative methods of calling the controller)?

Comment: How is your WebApi hosted in the worker role?

Comment: It's using Owin WebApp, the api is available when accessing it from another machine